# Равномерное расположение элементов RecyclerView в ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня есть RecyclerView, элементы которого располагаются горизонтально в ConstraintLayout. Как сделать чтобы расстояние между ними было одинаковое. Без RecyclerView я это делал с помощью chain, что делать в моем случае?

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivItem"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>\
```

item.xml

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, обернуть их в CardView , хотя не обязательно и задать Margin

```
android:layout_margin="2dp"
```

Comment: ну, это же не автоматическое выравнивание.. или я неправильно понял?

Comment: @Ilya Maximencko вроде бы как атрибут chain тоже есть в constraint/ app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" или app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle=”spread”

Comment: chainStyle не работает, видимо потому что recylcerview не создает chain, когда вставляет LinearLayoutы в ConstraintLayout, хотя если бы не создавал, думаю они наложились бы друг на друга..(прикрепил фото) странно, может еще какие-то варианты есть?

Comment: я вижу ваши элементы не в Constraint а в Linear лэйауте

Comment: это layout item для recycler view, а сам recyclerview лежит в constraintlayout

Comment: всё, сделал, немного не так как хотел, просто написал у RecyclerView width="wrap_content" и bias=0.5 чтобы оно по центру отображалось